# Как сделать резиновое изображение на весь экран, но с сохранением пропорций?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Как сделать так, чтобы при различном разрешении экрана, изображение растягивалось на всю высоту, если это вертикальное изображение, но сохраняло ширину. Если изображение горизонтальное, то оно растягивается по ширине, но не выше высоты экрана? Есть ли готовые скрипты или библиотеки для решения такой задачи?

Как не должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В CSS есть свойсто `object-fit`, для Вашей задачи его нужно задать на со значение `contain`. Более поднобно с ним можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

P.S. Оно работает во всех браузерах кроме IE. Для IE нужно подключить полифил.

Comment: _"кроме IE11"_ -то есть, например, в десятом IE оно работает?

Comment: Ну вообще идея хороша, но только там есть стрелки и это слайдер, мне нужно чтобы стрелки всегда находились слегка выходя за изображение, на фотке просто я их не захватил... За что искренне извиняюсь

Comment: Zebren я бы тогда добавил блок во внутрь с шириной, например, 50% и отценровал его. В блок добавил картинку и две кнопки кнопкам дал бы `position: absolute;`. Левой `left: -100px;`, правой `right: -100px;`. Картинке сообветвенно: `width:100%`; `height: 100%` и `object-fit: contain`.

Answer (score 0):

> Ну вообще идея хороша, но только там есть стрелки и это слайдер, мне нужно чтобы стрелки всегда находились слегка выходя за изображение, на фотке просто я их не захватил... За что искренне извиняюсь

Тогда такой вариант

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.img-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img-content .wrap {
  display: inline-table;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-content img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 0;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.prev {left: -50px;}
.button.next {right: -50px;}
```

```html
<div class="img-content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="button prev"></div>
    <img src="https://sertiki.ru/userfiles//editor/maxfoto/143_sertifikat-rpo.png">
    <div class="button next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```